# Displaying users profile information

Tags: php

I am having problems with displaying out users profile information when clicking on their profile. the data shown is my own when logged in so it isn't switching. I cannot find the issue and wondering where I maybe going wrong?

So the information should be showing out on profile.php

```
if (isset($_GET['username']) === true && empty ($_GET['username']) === false) {
    $username = $_GET['username'];

    if (user_exists($username) === true) {
        $user_id  = user_id_from_username($username);   
        $profile_data = user_data($user_id, 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email');        
    ?>  
    <h1><?php echo $profile_data['first_name']; ?> profile</h1>
    <p><?php echo $profile_data['email'] ?></p> 
    <?php

    } else {
        echo 'Sorry, that user does not exist';
    }
    } else {
        header('Location: index.php');
    exit();
}
```

It shows my information and not the user I am trying to view. If I type in a bogus username on the URL it does error out and say they do not exist.

Here is my script to pick the data out of the database:

```
if (logged_in() === true) {
    $session_user_id = $_SESSION ['user_id'];
    $user_data = user_data($session_user_id, 'user_id', 'username', 'password', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'type', 'profile');
    if(user_active($user_data['username']) === false) {
        session_destroy();
        header('Location: index.php');
        exit();

    }
}

$errors = array();
```

Im using a .htaccess file o initliase the vanity URL

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCon %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCon %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /profile.php?username=$1
```

so my URL would look like this...

http://mywebsite.com/myname

here is the function for user_data

```
function user_data($user_id) {
    $data = array();
    $user_id = (int)$unser_id;

    $func_num_args = func_num_args();
    $func_get_args = func_get_args();

    if ($func_num_args > 1){
        unset($func_get_args[0]);

        $fields = '`' . implode('`, `', $func_get_args) . '`';
        $data = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT $fields FROM `users` WHERE 'user_id' = $user_id"));


        return $data;
    }

}
```

And it does work by changing myname but not switching the user data on the profile page to other users data.

**As requested: user_exists() function**

```
function user_exists($username) {
    $username = sanitize($username);
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(`user_id`) FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '$username'");
    return (mysql_result($query, 0) == 1) ? true : false;
}
```

Comment: Sounds like the problem is in either `user_id_from_username()` or `user_data()`. Since you haven't posted these, there's no way we can help.

Comment: I have added the user_data function

Comment: wait, you're saying that showing your information when you're logged in is wrong? something I don't understand I guess, I thought that would be the correct behaviour

Comment: Echo `user_id_from_username($username)`.

Comment: **edit:** misinterpreted the brackets

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier No, my information is correct, if I edit the username at the end of the url it still shows MY profile data and not theirs on profile.php

Comment: @BrettSantore but even by removing this it still shows my profile information and not the data of another user?

Comment: @user3746168 that's exactly my point. aren't you still the logged user? isn't the script showing the *logged* user informations? what happens when you log in as another user?

Comment: Echo `user_id_from_username($username)` to see if that's the value you expect. @FélixGagnon-Grenier it's a get request so he can change that information in the url.

Comment: It is showing my information BUT when i want to view another persons profile it is still showing MY profile data on their profile page. It isnt showing their profile data.

Comment: @BrettSantore ok so it is showing the user id of that user but still showing my profile data above so we are getting closer

Comment: Paste `user_exists()` **edit:** since this is returning false

Comment: you want to see the user_exists() function?

Comment: @BrettSantore Amy ideas im stumped? If I change the username now in the url it shows their user id but still showing my profile data?

Comment: Set your `error_reporting` to a level sensible for debugging, _now_.

Comment: `user_data` should be `$user_id = (int)$user_id;`

Comment: @BrettSantore spotted the typo in the function, now i have corrected it fails to log me in!! :S

Comment: @CBroe Where would the best place to be place to debug here? I am a tad lost

Comment: So by doing some debugging has caused more headache - I have found that 'Undefined variable: unser_id' should be set as user_id but by changing this causes me to not be able to login anymore :S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
function user_data($user_id, $fields = '*') {

  // type cast to int
  $user_id = (int) $user_id;

  // if an array is passed, we implode the array to get fields,
  // otherwise we return all rows
  if (is_array($fields))
  {
    $fields = implode('`, `', $fields) . '`';
  }

  //build query, with LIMIT 1 , I assume username is unique
  $qry = "SELECT {$fields} FROM `users` WHERE 'user_id' = {$user_id} LIMIT 1";
  $sql = mysql_query($qry);
  $result = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql);

  // if we have a result, return it, otherwise return false
  return (mysql_num_rows($sql) == 1) ? $result : false ;

}
```

to be used:

```
$profile_data = user_data($user_id, array('user_id', 'username', 'password', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'type', 'profile'));
```

or

```
$fields = array(
  'user_id',
  'username',
  'password',
  'first_name',
  'last_name',
  'email',
  'type',
  'profile'
);

$profile_data = user_data($user_id, $fields);
```

Comment: Also, for new development, if you can, use either `PDO` or `mysqli_*` functions.

Comment: To be used part... is that going on profile.php? what am i replacing?

Comment: Do you have skype at all?